# How to change icon size of UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon)?

Tags: java, swing, icons, uimanager

I'm working on swing project.
I've `jErrorMsgLabel` to show error message.
I want to use L&F icons for `jErrorMsgLabel` same as below snap showing information message **"Please specify a value for Database:"**
[image]

So I did

```
jErrorMsgLabel.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));`
```

But icon size is same as `JOptionPane`

How can I change icon size?
Or is there any other way around to show error messages?

Answer (score 3):

You need to scale the image yourself:

```
ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
Image image = icon.getImage();
Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
Icon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon( scaledImage );
yourLabel.setIcon( scaledIcon );
```

Of course whenever you scale an image larger you will get pixilation.

Edit:

Following is the code that paints the Icon to a BufferedImage which can then be scaled:

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"); 
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics(); 
icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0); 
g.dispose(); 
ImageIcon errorIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(15, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak Sorry, I was in a rush when I posted the answer. The concept does work, I just had a few typos. See updated code.

Comment: And with your code getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusIcon cannot be cast to javax.swing.ImageIcon`

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak, yes, I only tested with the default LAF. Nimbus will not be straight forward since the `NimbusIcon` does not support a getImage() method. You would first need to paint the Icon to a BufferedImage, then you could scale the BufferedImage.

Comment: `Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");  
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);  

        Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();  

        icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);  
        g.dispose();  

        ImageIcon errorIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(15, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));`